# Let $p$ be an odd prime, and let $p-1$ be a multiple of 4. Prove $\mathbb F_p^{\times}$ contains an element of order 4.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $G=\mathbb F_p^{\times}$. Consider the homomorphism $\varphi: G \to G$ defined by $\varphi(x)=x^2$. The image of $\varphi$ has order $\frac{p-1}{2}$. This is an even integer because $\frac{p-1}{2} = 2 \frac{p-1}{4}$, and $\frac{p-1}{4}$ is an integer by assumption. Since groups that have even order have an element of order 2, the image of $\varphi$ contains an element of order 2, call it $y$. $y$ has a preimage $x$ where $x^2=y$. Since $y$ has order 2, $x$ has order 4.

My question: Am I implicitly using any of these facts?

1. The kernel is $\{1,-1\}$ or equivalently $\{1,p-1\}$ (because a polynomial with degree $2$, in this case $x^2-1$ has at most $2$ zeros, and $\{1,-1\}$ are zeros of $x^2-1$).
2. First Sylow theorem

I think the kernel is used to compute the order of the image, but I think I don't need the First Sylow theorem because I use the weaker fact that a group of even order has an element of order 2.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The group $\;G\;\;$ is of order $\;p-1=0\pmod 4\;$ and since thus it has one unique subgroup of any order dividing its order,  it also has an element of order $\;4\;$ (in fact, exactly two elements of order four)

Comment: @DonAntonio I don't think I understand. If $G$ has order $n$, and $m$ divides $n$, $G$ doesn't necessarily have a subgroup of order $m$ right?

Comment: You're using the first result to show that $\#\operatorname{im} \varphi = \frac{1}{2} \#G$. (That wouldn't be the case, if for example, $G = \mathbb{Z}_2\times \mathbb{Z}_2$; but $G$ is cyclic.)

Comment: @anomaly If $G$ is cyclic of order $2n$, then $G^2$ has order $n$?

Comment: @anomaly What is the exact relationship between $G$ is cyclic and kernel is $\{1,-1\}$?

Comment: @EkhinTaylorR.Wilson Yes, it does...if the group is abelian. And if the groups is cyclic, then it has **exactly one subgroup** of any order dividing the group's. And the subgroups are also cyclic, of course again.

Comment: @DonAntonio Are you utilising [A Converse to Lagrange's Theorem for Finite Abelian Groups](http://mathonline.wikidot.com/a-converse-to-lagrange-s-theorem-for-finite-abelian-groups) which can be proven without Sylow?

Comment: For point 1, yes. For point 2, you use Cauchy's theorem.

Comment: @Bernard For point 1, how?

Comment: When you say $\varphi(G)$ has order $\frac{p-1}2$, you use implicitly thaht any square $n \in \mathbf F_p^\times$ has two square roots, which comes down to asserting the polynomial $x^2-1$, the roots thereof constitute $\ker\varphi$, has roots equal to $1$ and $-1$.  Actually, one might argue that  it ultimately relies on the fact that a polynomial of degree $d$ over a field has at most $d$ roots.

Comment: @Ekhin This is generally true for finite abelian groups because a general theorem about them (decomposition and stuff. No needed now), but in this case it is much simpler since $\;G\;$ is **cyclic**. It is usually taught way before the Fundamental theorem of finitely generated abelian groups that a cyclic finite group has a unique subgroup of any order dividing the group's.

Comment: @DonAntonio Fundamental theorem of cyclic groups?

Comment: @Bernard I just realised that I wasn't sure why $\varphi(G)$ has order $\frac{p-1}{2}$. Now I'm sure thanks to you. Anyway, the fact that a polynomial of degree $d$ over a field has at most $d$ zeros is what proves both that $\varphi(G)$ has order $\frac{p-1}{2}$ and $\ker \varphi = \{ 1, -1 \}$, but $\ker \varphi = \{ 1, -1 \}$ by itself does not imply that $\varphi(G)$ has order $\frac{p-1}{2}$?

Comment: Just because in a field, if $x^2=y^2\;(\ne 0)$, then $x=\pm y$, so  squares come in pairs (except for $0$, of course).

Answer (score 1):

Note that we have by Wilson theorem $$(p-1)! \equiv -1 \mod p$$

Then
\begin{align}-1& =(p-1)!\\
& = \prod_{k=1}^{p-1 \over 2} k(p-k)\\
& = (-1)^{p-1 \over 2}\prod_{k=1}^{p-1 \over 2}k^2\\
&=  a^2 \qquad (\text{ because  } p\equiv 1 \mod 4)\end{align}
Hence $a^2=-1$ and so $a $ has order $4$.